# how to pass properties to JS file inside a PHP include

Tags: javascript, php

First, I build a single php page with

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function ShowDIV()
 { 
    if (popUpDiv.style.display=="none") 
    {popUpDiv.style.display="block"; blanket.style.display="block"; }
    else 
    { popUpDiv.style.display="none";  blanket.style.display="none";}
} 
</script>
```

and in my code I can call this function

```
 <a href="#" onClick="ShowDIV();">
```

everything works...

but then I wanted to separate that file into

main.php  (which now includes header.php)

in my header.php, I added the same JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function ShowDIV()
 { 
    if (popUpDiv.style.display=="none") 
    {popUpDiv.style.display="block"; blanket.style.display="block"; }
    else 
    { popUpDiv.style.display="none";  blanket.style.display="none";}
} 
</script>
```

but now it doesn't work, my console tells me:

```
Cannot read property display of Undefined
```

Does it mean I have to pass somehow the propreties to the new header.php file?

Comment: put the js content into a separate js file and call that file instead of putting it in header.

Comment: I tried that also, I get the same result...

Comment: @Aditya I tried `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="showDIV.js"></script>`  all files are in the same folder

Comment: where is blanket in your code  ?

Comment: @AnandPatel I don't understand your question.. what does this mean?

Comment: blanket is selector right ?

Comment: @AnandPatel ok, you gave me the hint.... I had the blanket code in both main and header... I deleted it from main and now it works.. thanks a lot.

Comment: put your html code .this is dom property unable to find html at client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be Selector for blanket so that you can access its properties, please check your code for blanket, right now what happening there is no blanket selector that`s why its undefined.

so please check selector is exist then only you can access its properties.

EDIT

you should never have two elements on the same page with the same ID.